# How to fix GraphQL error - Not Authorized

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I keep geting this error:

> Error: GraphQL error: Not Authorized!

Code is:

```
const queries = gql`
  query {
    mystreak
  }
`;

  render() {
    return (
      <Query query={queries}>
        {({ loading, error, data }) => {
          console.log(loading);
          console.log(error);
          console.log(data.mystreak);
        }}
      </Query>
)
}
```

App is built in React.js, and I am pretty new to GraphQL.

Also data is undefined.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you use Apollo.
We are lacking a lot of information, especially regarding your backend, but it looks like you are missing an Authorization header in your http requests:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/http.html#options

```
const link = createHttpLink({
    uri: "/graphql",
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer <your token here>'
    }
});
```

Check the documentation of your backend for the token value.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by removing `eas: projectId` from `app.json`:

```
"extra": {
  "eas": {
    "projectId": "a1b2c3d4-e5f6-g7h8i9-j1k2-l3m4n5o6p7"
  }
}
```

I need a build for development, the company's Expo project ID is different than my account's project ID, thus the problem...